# flutter: IconButton onPressed didn't get called

Tags: android, ios, click, flutter

I put a list of widget as action in `Scaffold` appBar, but they didn't respond when I press them, I have a `floatingButton` in the scene too and it works perfectly.

```
appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
            widget.title,
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'vazir'
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
            highlightColor: Colors.pink,
            onPressed: _onSearchButtonPressed(),
          ),
        ],
      ),

void _onSearchButtonPressed() {
    print("search button clicked");
  }
```

even if I put IconButton in a `Row` or `Column` widget , not in `appBar`, it doesn't work again.
**Answer:**
thanks to siva Kumar, I had a mistake in calling function , we should call it in this way:

```
onPressed: _onSearchButtonPressed, // without parenthesis.
```

or this way:

```
onPressed: (){
    _onSearchButtonPressed();
},
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

please try with my answer it will work.

```
    appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(
        widget.title,
      style: new TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'vazir'
      ),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
    actions: <Widget>[
      new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
        highlightColor: Colors.pink,
        onPressed: (){_onSearchButtonPressed();},
      ),
    ],
  ),

void _onSearchButtonPressed() {
print("search button clicked");
}
```

Comment: If possible, try adding an explanation as to why the code posted in the question didn't work and how does your solution mitigate it.

Answer (score 4):

Bump into the question while searching for other solution.

The answer should be:

```
onPressed: _onSearchButtonPressed,
```

Without the () brackets. Since they carry the same signature, there is no need to wrap them around another anonymous / lambda function.

Answer (score -2):

Actually we need to set the VoidCallback for `onPressed` property, When we tap on icon that VoidCallback is called .
We also set null if we don't need any response.

```
class PracticeApp extends StatelessWidget {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
     floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
     tooltip: "Add",
     child: new Icon(Icons.add),
     onPressed: () { setState(); },
    ),
  );
 }
}

void setState() {
  print("Button Press");
}
```

We can also directly pass the call back like this

```
onPressed: () { setState(() { _volume *= 1.1; }); }
```

Example for `null`

```
onPressed: null
```